# Laravel eloquent run a query on a query result

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel Eloquent and trying to query my results from a query I ran.  I have spent a lot of time googling, but have not found anything that has helped.  I have a query which I called `$poolResults`.  If the user enters a city I want to further filter those results based on matching zip code or if the user entered a city. Here is my second query.

If the user enters `$locationOfUser`, filter `$poolResults` where any of the following are found (the zip code, city, or city search).

```
 if($locationOfUser != ''){
                $poolResults = $poolResults->where('city', $locationOfUser)
                    ->orwhere('users.city_search', $locationOfUser)
                    ->orwhereIn('users.zip', $zipCodes)->get();
            }
```

I am getting this error screen as a result.

[image]

Comment: Functions are case sensitive `orWhere()`, not `orwhere()` (same goes for `orwhereIn()`, should be `orWhereIn()`.

Comment: Hi, try to store the first query's results in an associative array then your filters will be filtering the data in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out parameter grouping did the trick

```
DB::table('users')
            ->where('name', '=', 'John')
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where('votes', '>', 100)
                      ->orWhere('title', '=', 'Admin');
            })
            ->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#parameter-grouping

Answer (score -3):

this `orwhere` operator doesn't exist you can use `orderBy` or something like that.

Comment: The orderBy method is used on a found collection. He is wanting orWhere to get the collection.